# How do you use WinHTTP to do SSL with a self signed cert

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ssl, winhttp

I seem to be having issues with this, and in the spirit of having a generic question that can be referenced by others, I am looking for a good example of using SSL.

More specifically, I am getting the error 0x00002F8F from WinHttpSendRequest, which is ERROR_INTERNET_DECODING_FAILED (which indicates to me that its a cert error). I have imported the cert on this machine, and am able to pull up the page in IE without a cert error.

TLDR: How do you use WinHTTP with a self signed cert?

```
// pochttpclient.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "winhttp.h"
#include "wchar.h"
 
 
 
// SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) example
// compile for console
 
void main()
{
    HINTERNET hOpen = 0;
    HINTERNET hConnect = 0;
    HINTERNET hRequest = 0;
    IStream *stream = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;
 
    while (1)
    {
        hOpen = WinHttpOpen(L"Aurora Console App", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
 
        if (!hOpen) {
            wprintf(L"WinHttpOpen failed (0x%.8X)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
 
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hOpen, L"www.codeproject.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);
 
        if (!hConnect) {
            wprintf(L"WinHttpConnect failed (0x%.8X)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
 
        LPCWSTR types[2];
        types[0] = L"text/html";
        types[1] = 0;
 
        // use flag WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE to initiate SSL
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", L"KB/IP/NagTPortScanner.aspx",
                NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, types, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);
 
        if (!hRequest)
        {
            wprintf(L"WinHttpOpenRequest failed (0x%.8X)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
 
        if (!WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            wprintf(L"WinHttpSendRequest failed (0x%.8X)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        if (!WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, 0))
        {
            wprintf(L"WinHttpReceiveResponse failed (0x%.8X)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        // query remote file size, set haveContentLength on success and dwContentLength to the length
        wchar_t szContentLength[32];
        DWORD cch = 64;
        DWORD dwHeaderIndex = WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX;
 
        BOOL haveContentLength = WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH, NULL,
                &szContentLength, &cch, &dwHeaderIndex);
 
        DWORD dwContentLength;
        if (haveContentLength) dwContentLength = _wtoi(szContentLength);
 
        // read the response into memory stream
        hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, true, &stream);
        if (hr) {
            wprintf(L"CreateStreamOnHGlobal failed (0x%.8X)\n", hr);
            break;
        }
        // allocate buffer for streaming received data
        unsigned char* p = new unsigned char[4096];
        if (!p)
        {
            wprintf(L"failed to allocate buffer\n");
            break;
        }
        // to receive all data, we need to enter a loop
        DWORD dwReceivedTotal = 0;
        while (WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &cch) && cch)
        {
            if (cch > 4096) cch = 4096;
            dwReceivedTotal += cch;
 
            // display number of received bytes
            if (haveContentLength)
            {
                wprintf(L"received %d of %d (%d%%)%c", dwReceivedTotal, dwContentLength, 
                    dwReceivedTotal*100/dwContentLength, 13);
            }
            else {
                wprintf(L"received %d (unknown length)%c", dwReceivedTotal, 10);
            }
 
            WinHttpReadData(hRequest, p, cch, &cch);
            // write into stream
            hr = stream->Write(p, cch, NULL);
            if (hr)
            {
                wprintf(L"failed to write data to stream (0x%.8X)\n", hr);
            }
        }
 
        delete p;
        wprintf(L"\n\nreceived all data.\n");
        // terminate the sream with a NULL
        p = NULL;
        stream->Write(&p, 1, NULL);
        // get pointer to stream bytes
        wprintf(L"getting HGLOBAL from stream...\n");
        HGLOBAL hgl;
        hr = GetHGlobalFromStream(stream, &hgl);
        if (hr) {
            wprintf(L"GetHGlobalFromStream failed (0x%.8X)\n", hr);
            break;
        }
        wprintf(L"locking memory...\n");
        p = (unsigned char*)GlobalLock(hgl);
        if (!p)
        {
            wprintf(L"GlobalLock failed (0x%.8X)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        wprintf(L"displaying received data...\n");
        // terminate the string at 1024 bytes (MessageBox lag)
        //if (dwReceivedTotal > 1024) dwReceivedTotal = 1024;
        //*p[dwReceivedTotal] = 0;
 
        MessageBox(0, (LPCWSTR)p, L"", 0);
        GlobalUnlock(hgl);
 
        break;
    }
    // delete stream and close handles
    if (stream) stream->Release();
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hOpen) WinHttpCloseHandle(hOpen);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For WinHTTP, in order to accept/allow SSL validation failures, you must first make the request and allow it to fail, then disable the security checks and retry the operation on the request handle.  Something along the lines of:

```
// Certain circumstances dictate that we may need to loop on WinHttpSendRequest
// hence the do/while
do
{
    retry = false;
    result = NO_ERROR;

    // no retry on success, possible retry on failure
    if(WinHttpSendRequest(
        mHRequest,
        WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
        0,
        optionalData,
        optionalLength,
        totalLength,
        NULL
        ) == FALSE)
    {
        result = GetLastError();

        // (1) If you want to allow SSL certificate errors and continue
        // with the connection, you must allow and initial failure and then
        // reset the security flags. From: "HOWTO: Handle Invalid Certificate
        // Authority Error with WinInet"
        // http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;182888
        if(result == ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE)
        {
            DWORD dwFlags =
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA |
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_WRONG_USAGE |
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;

            if(WinHttpSetOption(
                mHRequest,
                WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
                &dwFlags,
                sizeof(dwFlags)))
            {
                retry = true;
            }
        }
        // (2) Negotiate authorization handshakes may return this error
        // and require multiple attempts
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        else if(result == ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST)
        {
            retry = true;
        }
    }
} while(retry);
```

Comment: I just banged my head against exactly this problem, refusing to believe that this stupid repetition is needed. And indeed it is possible: 1.  get session handle with WinHttpOpen 2. get connection handle using WinHttpConnect. 3. get request handle using WinHttpOpenRequest (use the WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE to turn on TLS. This is NOT the same set of flags as the WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS). 4. Use WinHttpSetOption as described above on the obtained request handle. 5. WinHttpSendRequest to send the request.

Comment: wow this is stupid. who thinks this is ok? i use boost/beast to do mtls auth to rest endpoints. the cert is attached to the session before the request and it just works. no retries required

Comment: You are a life-saver! I would NOT have figured this out!

Answer (score 0):

if you happen to be using MFC wrapper classes:

```
CHttpFile* pFile = m_pConnection->OpenRequest(nRequestVerb, strRequest, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT | dwFlags);
...
DWORD dwSecurity = 0;
if (pFile->QueryOption(INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, dwSecurity))
{
    dwSecurity |= SECURITY_IGNORE_ERROR_MASK;
    pFile->SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, dwSecurity);
}
...
pFile->SendRequest(strRequestHeaders); // throws exception without IGNORE_ERROR_MASK
```

Note that security flags can be set on CHttpFile before SendRequest.  You don't have to wait until error/exception occurs.